# Expression Tree and Display

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to get the expression tree working with my data setup.

The following is the data and what i return to my view such as `return View(contacts1)`.

```
var contacts1 = (from con in db.Contacts
join conorg in db.ContactOrganizations on con.ContactID equals conorg.ContactID
join org in db.Organizations on conorg.OrganizationID equals org.OrganizationID
where con.CenterID == cID && conorg.IsActive == 1 && con.IsDeleted == 0
orderby con.LastName

select new ContactView
{
        ContactID = con.ContactID,
        FName = con.FirstName,
        LName = con.LastName,
        Title = con.Title,
        Organization = (org == null ? "(none)" : org.Name),
        City = con.City,
        State = con.State,
        DateCreated = con.DateCreated,
        Notes = con.Notes,
        Status = (con.Status == 1 ? "Active" : "Inactive")
}).ToList();
```

The code I have for my expression tree is the following, but it is giving me an error that the "ContactID" property is null (`System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: property`).  The query that I am trying to create is `queryableData.Where(c => c.ContactID == 38 || c.ContactID == 39)`.  Then I want to integrate the results with the contactview above to display on the view.

```
IQueryable<ContactView> queryableData = contacts1.AsQueryable<ContactView>();

ParameterExpression pe = Expression.Parameter(typeof(string), "c");

Expression left = Expression.Property(pe, typeof(string).GetProperty("ContactID"));
Expression right = Expression.Constant(38, typeof(int));
Expression e1 = Expression.Equal(left, right);

left = Expression.Property(pe, typeof(string).GetProperty("ContactID"));
right = Expression.Constant(39, typeof(int));
Expression e2 = Expression.GreaterThan(left, right);

Expression predicateBody = Expression.OrElse(e1, e2);

MethodCallExpression whereCallExpression = Expression.Call(
    typeof(Queryable),
    "Where",
    new Type[] { queryableData.ElementType },
    queryableData.Expression,
    Expression.Lambda<Func<string, bool>>(predicateBody, new ParameterExpression[] { pe }));

IQueryable<string> results = queryableData.Provider.CreateQuery<string>(whereCallExpression);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is from memory, but I think you're using `Expression.Property` and `Expression.Parameter` incorrectly. Try this:

```
ParameterExpression pe = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Contact), "c");
// ...
Expression left = Expression.Property(pe, typeof(Contact).GetProperty("ContactID"));
Expression right = Expression.Constant(38, typeof(int));
Expression e1 = Expression.Equal(left, right);
// And so on...
```

Comment: Thanks! Instead of changing the 'typeof' to Contact, I changed it to ContactView.  But now it is giving me this error: ParameterExpression of type 'ContactView' cannot be used for delegate parameter of type 'System.String'.  It is referring to the following code section.

     MethodCallExpression whereCallExpression = Expression.Call(
    typeof(Queryable),
    "Where",
    new Type[] { queryableData.ElementType },
    queryableData.Expression,
    Expression.Lambda<Func<string, bool>>(predicateBody, new ParameterExpression[] { pe }));

Comment: When I changed 'typeof' to Contact, it gave me the same error

Comment: I think you need to change that to `Expression.Lambda<Func<Contact, bool>>`. The `Func<Contact,bool>` is a function that takes a `Contact` as a parameter, and returns true or false depending on whether or not it should be filtered in or out.